# Changing main window content

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to make a welcome screen where user could select 1 of 3 program "subcategories". Than when he selects it the whole main window content will change appropriately to selected category.
What is the best way to make this, or the simpliest (I'm not very good with WPF)? 
I'm also interested in MVVM solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement the welcome screen and the subcategories as individual UserControls. Each one of those UserControls would then be the only content of the main window and you could just swap them as required to display the right one to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may just want a [TabControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol.aspx). If not a screen with three buttons?

Comment: I need a screen with 3 buttons :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Bindings you could use a content control and bind the `Content` property to say `CurrentContent`.

The default value is the selection control, when the select command is executed your view model creates the required view and just set it to the `CurrentContent` property. WPF will revaluate the binding and replace the selection screen with the new control.